# How to delete the old content of Elasticsearch each time I save the new content?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I use `PutElasticsearch` in order to save the content of FlowFile in Elasticsearch.
However, in this case, I always append the mapping of Elasticsearch. How can I always previously delete the existing content of the mapping and then save the new one, i.e. the content of FlowFile?

Answer (score 1):

The data in Elasticsearch is immutable. So if you insert new data with the same **id** the data will be overriden. So you must use same id.

Comment: How can I extract id in order to know it? I want to avoid any hardcoding. Also I found the option "update" in `PutElasticsearch`, but have not checked it yet.